# live-server : The term 'live-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm-live-server

live-server : The term 'live-server' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct
and try again.
At line:1 char:1

- live-server
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (live-server:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
  ```

Already installed node js

PS C:\Javascript\complete-javascript-course-master\13-Advanced-DOM-Bankist\starter> node -v
v16.1.0

Answer (score 1):

Most likely if you had just installed it, it won't be in your PATH yet. You would need to restart your terminal for your PATH variable to update.